# TypeError: must be real number, not str in TSNE for a credit card fraud detection using auto encoder

Tags: python, typeerror, tsne

This is the code get from github, where is about a credit card fraud detection using auto encoder. However, when I try to run it give me an error message about TypeError: must be real number, not str

```
def tsne_plot(x1, y1, name="graph.png"):
    tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, random_state=0)
    X_t = tsne.fit_transform(x1)

    plt.figure(figsize=(12, 8))
    plt.scatter(X_t[np.where(y1 == 0), 0], X_t[np.where(y1 == 0), 1], marker='o', color='g', linewidth='1', alpha=0.8, label='Non Fraud')
    plt.scatter(X_t[np.where(y1 == 1), 0], X_t[np.where(y1 == 1), 1], marker='o', color='r', linewidth='1', alpha=0.8, label='Fraud')

    plt.legend(loc='best');
    plt.savefig(name);
    plt.show();
    
tsne_plot(X, Y, "original.png")
```

I was expecting to get a plotting of fraud and non fraud. The error message is as below :

```
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7256\3319091206.py in <module>
     11     plt.show();
     12 
---> 13 tsne_plot(X, Y, "original.png")

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_7256\3319091206.py in tsne_plot(x1, y1, name)
      8 
      9     plt.legend(loc='best');
---> 10     plt.savefig(name);
     11     plt.show();
```

Comment: Please [edit] to post the exact error message, which usually indicates which line of code is raising the Exception. Because here in your post, it's not clear which is expecting a real number, not string.